# Get list of users in a group in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, users, groups

How to get a list of usernames assigned to a group in FreeBSD 11.1?

[This Question](https://serverfault.com/q/240804/142214) asks for a list of users *or* a list of groups.

[This Question](https://serverfault.com/q/239083/142214) asks for users who happen to be members of multiple specific groups.

➥ But how to ask simply for a list of users currently assigned to a single specific group, such `wheel`?

I prefer a solution in a single command if possible. But if not feasible, a script would be useful and educational.

Comment: Is a moderately complicated script parsing /etc/passwd and /etc/groups OK, or do you want a system command?

Comment: @Law29 Either, or both. I added note in Question.

Comment: Why not just `getent group groupname`?

Comment: @NasirRiley Can you show example?

Comment: @BasilBourque It's just like I typed it. Replace groupname with the group that you want.

Answer (score 5):

You can select users with specific group from list of all users given by `pw` utility:

```
pw usershow -P -a | grep groupname
```

Result will be something like:

```
Login Name: username1     #1024         Group: groupname          #1002
Login Name: username2     #1025         Group: groupname          #1002
```

Comment: This is useful because it indicates the `pw` utility. No idea why it was downvoted (and my three-month-old answer got just downvoted too).

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to show all users in a certain group under FreeBSD is:

```
# pw groupshow groupname
```

Answer (score 1):

Disregarding system scripts like `getent`, users can be in a group in two ways: either it is their principal group, defined in /etc/passwd, or they have it as a secondary group in /etc/groups.

```
GROUPID=1000
sed -rn "s/^[^:]*:[^:]*:$GROUPID://p" < /etc/group | tr ',' '\n'
sed -rn "s/^([^:]*):[^:]*:[^:]*:$GROUPID:.*/\\1/p" < /etc/passwd
```

Should do it nicely. `awk` would probably look nicer...

```
GROUPID=1000
awk -F: -v "g=$GROUPID" '{if ($3==g) print $1;}' /etc/passwd
awk -F: -v "g=$GROUPID" '{if ($3==g) print $4;}' /etc/group | tr ',' '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-list-all-members-of-a-group/ thread show multiple ways of doing this. I personally prefer members method. but the method below is native and works well.

```
$ grep 'grpup-name-here' /etc/group
$ grep 'ftponly' /etc/group
$ grep -i --color 'ftponly' /etc/group
```

Answer (score 0):

pw group show ftpgroup

> ftpgroup:*:2001:

pw group show wheel

> wheel:*:0:root,fred,carl

pw group show video

> video:*:44:lightdm

pw user show ftp

> ftp:*:2002:2001::0:0:PureFTP user:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin

```
pw user show carl
```

> carl:$6$SDkXHtJyIp53egpl$XBg3cuem.RLW63Pa0E16Qw4hmc96lXFgC/fTwCSnDEgYE/OhairDv.mX193ToC6PaQfsp.NegsqEYMHSMxinE/:1003:1003::0:0:Carl
> Dubak:/home/carl:/usr/local/bin/fish

```
pw user show fred
```

> fred:$6$alWrCEOtGuU1Bx7t$oWXCNkP4t4yQVn5.0ZKuJqAtCNXkR5ywcdI0Guxqv3myDI.u/qrqUzBX7BW4jmwLFHDd00tCdyGt3A9Q6T4s4/:1002:1002::0:0:Fred
> Finster:/home/fred:/usr/local/bin/fish

```
getent passwd {carl}
```

> carl:$6$SDkXHtJyIp53egpl$XBg3cuem.RLW63Pa0E16Qw4hmc96lXFgC/fTwCSnDEgYE/OhairDv.mX193ToC6PaQfsp.NegsqEYMHSMxinE/:1003:1003:Carl
> Dubak:/home/carl:/usr/local/bin/fish

```
getent passwd {fred}
```

> fred:$6$alWrCEOtGuU1Bx7t$oWXCNkP4t4yQVn5.0ZKuJqAtCNXkR5ywcdI0Guxqv3myDI.u/qrqUzBX7BW4jmwLFHDd00tCdyGt3A9Q6T4s4/:1002:1002:Fred
> Finster:/home/fred:/usr/local/bin/fish

```
id
```

> id=0(root) gid=0(wheel) groups=0(wheel),5(operator)

```
id 1003
```

uid=1003(carl) gid=1003(carl) groups=1003(carl),0(wheel),5(operator)

```
id 1002
```

> uid=1002(fred) gid=1002(fred)
> groups=1002(fred),0(wheel),5(operator),145(webcamd)

```
id 5
```

> uid=5(kmem) gid=65533(nogroup) groups=65533(nogroup)

```
id {operator}
```

> uid=2(operator) gid=5(operator) groups=5(operator)